# get foreign key fields from DbSet in EF6 database First

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I have a working data base and i am using EntityFramework to manipulate its data. I ended with having `DbSet<Type>` and `DbContext` and I need a way to retrieve any foreign key in the anonymous type using any available way

Code Example of auto generated EF classes

```
public partial class Country
{
   public int ID { get; private set; } //primaryKey
   public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public partial class City
{
   public int City_ID { get; private set; } //primaryKey
   public int Country_ID { get; private set; } //ForeignKey Needed To get For Any Entity or Class
   public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Auto Generated DbContext Child

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
   public virtual DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
   public virtual DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get all foreignKeys like `Country_ID` from `DbSet<{UnknownType}>`

Answer (score 0):

Properties in Entity classes doesnt have any information about its relationships without DataAnnotation. All Relationships data is defined in OnModelCreating in your context.

Only reasonable way I can think of is by `System.Reflection` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` for foreign keys. [Tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Your entity classes would look like this.

```
public partial class Country
{
     [Key]
     public int ID { get; private set; }
     public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
} 

public partial class City
{
     [Key]
     public int City_ID { get; private set; } 

     [ForeignKey("Country")]
     public int Country_ID { get; private set; } 
     public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can make method which will look thru properties of your class and find all properties which has defined foreign key. This method could looks like this.

```
Public static List<string> GetForeignKeyNamesOfClass(Type classType)
{
      List<string> foreignNameList = new List<string>();
      PropertyInfo[] propertyInfoArray = classType.GetProperties();

      foreach(PropertyInfo info in propertyInfoArray)
      {
           if(Attribute.IsDefined(info, typeof(ForeignKeyAttribute)))
           {
                foreignNameList.add(info.Name)
           }
      }

      return foreignNameList;
}
```

And then you will call it like

```
GetForeignKeyNamesOfClass(typeof(City));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: the entity class are auto generated by EF and any changes may be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
it always has this comment
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //     This code was generated from a template.
    //
    //     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your 
    application.
    //     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: To be fair, you dont have to worry about it, if you wont go wild in entity classes. You will have to modify them anyway if you want to add documentation. If you wont add annotation for foreign keys, you will have hard times to make what you are asking. Relationships are defined in OnModelCreating in Context. Properties in entity classes dont have anything like it.

Comment: *Properties in Entity classes doesnt have any information about its relationships* -- No, but EF has extensive metadata. It's really not necessary to add attributes for this purpose.

Comment: @Gert Arnold Oh, everyday you learn something new. Thanks.